# How to plot (ggplot) two charts in the same plot R

Tags: r, ggplot2, charts, line

I need to compare 2 spectras by putting two charts in the same plot.

I cannot use the Melted function because my two data sets are 2 FTIR spectra with x numbers (wavenumber) not being quite the same.

I'm using this to plot the charts individually:

```
sacola57 <-read_excel("57.xlsx", sheet=1)

ggplot(sacola57, aes(x=Wavenumber,
                 y=Absorbance)) +
geom_line() +
theme_bw() +
theme(panel.grid.major = element_blank(), panel.grid.minor = element_blank())
```

and

```
PADRAO <-read_excel("padrao.xlsx", sheet=1)
ggplot(PADRAO, aes(x=Wavenumber,
               y=Absorbance)) +
geom_line() +
theme_bw() +
theme(panel.grid.major = element_blank(), panel.grid.minor = element_blank())
```

sacola57:

[image: Sacola SS]

padrao:

[image: Padrao SS]

I've tried this:

```
sacola58 <- read_excel("58.xlsx", sheet=1)
padrao <-read_excel("padrao.xlsx", sheet=1)
head(sacolas58)
head(padrao)

sacolas = merge(sacola58, padrao, by="Wavenumber")

sacolasMelted <- reshape2::melt(sacolas, id.var='Wavenumber')
head(sacolasMelted)

ggplot(sacolasMelted, aes(x=Wavenumber, y=value, col=variable,)) + geom_line() + theme_bw() +
labs( x = "Comprimento de onda (cm-1)", y = "Absorbância", color = "Amostra")+
scale_color_manual(labels = c("sacola branca", "sacola transparente", "sacola verde"), values = c("palevioletred2", "paleturquoise4", "red"))+
theme(panel.grid.major = element_blank(), panel.grid.minor = element_blank())
```

And return that:

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PH6o4.png) Wavenumber   Absorbance.x Absorbance.y
<0 row> ( row.names lenght 0)

```
head(sacola58
 +      )
# A tibble: 6 × 2
 Wavenumber Absorbance
   <dbl>      <dbl>
 1       650.     0.0341
 2       652.     0.0316
 3       654.     0.0285
 4       656.     0.0288
 5       658.     0.0306
 6       660.     0.0341
> head(padrao)
# A tibble: 6 × 2
 Wavenumber Absorbance
   <dbl>      <dbl>
1       650.      0.176
2       653.      0.180
3       656.      0.178
4       659.      0.171
5       662.      0.179
6       665.      0.173
```

Answer (score 0):

Does this work for you? I don't think you need to reshape your data, you can just stack the rows, provided you make a column to distinguish which spectra each row relates to.

```
sacola58 <- read_excel("58.xlsx", sheet=1)
sacola58$Src = "sacola58"
padrao <-read_excel("padrao.xlsx", sheet=1)
padrao$Src = "padrao"
combo <- rbind(sacola58, padrao)
```

I expect that will make something like this:

```
data.frame(
  stringsAsFactors = FALSE,
               Src = c("sacola58","sacola58",
                       "sacola58","sacola58","sacola58","sacola58","padrao",
                       "padrao","padrao","padrao","padrao","padrao"),
        Wavenumber = c(650L,652L,654L,656L,658L,
                       660L,650L,653L,656L,659L,662L,665L),
        Absorbance = c(0.0341,0.0316,0.0285,0.0288,
                       0.0306,0.0341,0.176,0.18,0.178,0.171,0.179,0.173)
) -> combo
```

Which you can plot like this:

```
ggplot(combo, aes(x=Wavenumber, y=Absorbance, col=Src))) +
  geom_line()
```

[image]